# Android ViewPager animation lag after first swipe

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, lag

I'm writing a calculator app for Android using the shunting yard infix2postfix method (well at least is some sort of it, since I'm relatively new to java). I have a ViewPager set for swiping between base keyboard and function keyboard. Both keyboards are fragments that contain simple buttons. The stack is a custom Object Stack class I implemented. The first time swiping the keyboards slide perfectly, but after the first fiew computations, the ViewPager starts lagging a bit, and I really don't understand why. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Here is the code for ViewPager:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
private Fragment[] keypads = new Fragment[NUM_PAGES];
private ViewPager pager;
private PagerAdapter pageradapter;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.keypadview);
    pageradapter = new KeypadSliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
    keypads[0] = new NumericKeypad();
    keypads[1] = new FunctionKeypad();
    }
private class KeypadSliderAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public KeypadSliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return keypads[position];
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

the base keyboard:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="*"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="."
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="="
        android:onClick="equalsKeyPressed"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="/"
        android:onClick="keyPressed"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
package com.soloinfor.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class NumericKeypad extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numeric_keypad, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

the function keyboard:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="sin()"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="functionKeyPressed"
        android:tag="sin("/>
    <Button android:text="cos()"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="functionKeyPressed"
        android:tag="cos("/>
    <Button android:text="tan()"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="functionKeyPressed"
        android:tag="tan("/>
    <Button android:text="π"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="functionKeyPressed"
        android:tag="π"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="ln()"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="functionKeyPressed"
        android:tag="ln("/>
    <Button android:text="log\u2081\u2080()"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="functionKeyPressed"
        android:tag="log\u2081\u2080("/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
package com.soloinfor.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class FunctionKeypad extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.function_keypad, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view hierarchy is huge. You should somehow flatten it, by avoiding nested `LinearLayout`s and employing `RelativeLayout` instead. Although you don't have heavy operations, the lag you are experiencing is due to inflation, layout and drawing the views.

Use Hierarchy Viewer and run LINT check. LINT will tell you all the possible ways to flatten the layouts.

Comment: I see the point, would GridLayout do as well? That way I'd only have one GridLayout root element and all the buttons nested inside it.